# JAVAFX - TextArea issue

Tags: javafx, textarea, builder, scene

I have strange problem which concerns to TextArea control. Using SceneBuilder I have apllied to it After a stylesheet:

```
.text-input {
  -fx-font-style: italic;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  -fx-text-fill: blue;
  -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

the input text just has become hidden:

[image]

What is more I can't format aligment of input text to be centered like:

-fx-text-aligment: center;

or

-fx-font-alignment: center

Should I replace all default styles for this control? How to do it?

Comment: It looks like you have a large border around the edge of the text area. Can you show how you defined that border?

Comment: It is only a panel background image, not border of TextArea :)